# Fourier Transforms of shifted sinc funtions

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions

I would like to calculate the Fourier transform of the following functions:

1. $$\left(\dfrac{\sin(\pi x\pm\pi n/2)}{\pi x\pm\pi n/2}\right)^2$$
2. $$\dfrac{\sin(\pi x+\pi n/2)}{\pi x+\pi n/2}\cdot\frac{\sin(\pi x-\pi n/2)}{\pi x-\pi n/2}$$

with $n \in\mathbb{N}$

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** the transform of $\sin (x\pi)/(x\pi)$ is a rectangle with height 1 between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

**Hint 2:** multiplication in one domain corresponds to convolution in the other domain.

**Hint 3:** shifting a function by $x_0$ corresponds to multiplication of its Fourier transform with $e^{\pm ix_0\omega}$.

**EDIT:** For solving (2.) we have the Fourier transforms of the two functions:
$$e^{\pm i\omega n/2}\text{rect}(\omega,\pi)$$

So the convolution becomes

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\Omega n/2}\text{rect}(\Omega,\pi)
e^{-i(\omega-\Omega) n/2}\text{rect}(\omega-\Omega,\pi)d\Omega=\\
=\frac{e^{-i\omega n/2}}{2\pi}\text{rect}(\omega,2\pi)\int_{\max (-\pi,\omega-\pi)}^{\min (\pi,\omega+\pi)}e^{j\Omega n}d\Omega$$

For $-2\pi<\omega < 0$ we get

$$\frac{e^{-i\omega n/2}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi+\omega}e^{j\Omega n}d\Omega$$

and for $0<\omega<2\pi$ we have

$$\frac{e^{-i\omega n/2}}{2\pi}\int_{\omega-\pi}^{\pi}e^{j\Omega n}d\Omega$$

I trust you can take it from here.

**EDIT 2:**
OK, some more help and the final solution. The first integral (for $-2\pi<\omega < 0$ ) evaluates to

$$\frac{e^{-i\omega n/2}}{2\pi}\frac{(-1)^n}{in}\left (e^{in\omega} -1\right )=
\frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi}\sin\frac{n\omega}{2}$$
and the second integral for positive $\omega$ is the same, just with the opposite sign. So the final result is

$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\pi}\text{sign}(\omega)\sin\frac{n\omega}{2},\quad
|\omega|<2\pi,\quad \text{(zero otherwise)}$$

Comment: Thanks. So:  $$1. \quad\quad \exp(\pm\pi in\xi)\cdot tri(\xi)$$ Is that correct?

Comment: Is that the same for the second product?

Comment: 1. yes, just watch out for scaling factors etc. For 2. just write down the convolution integral and see what happens. You can add your efforts to the question if there are problems, so we can see where exactly you need more help (if you need any ...).

Comment: It holds also for the second one. $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\quad \exp(-\pi in\xi)\cdot rect(\eta-\xi)\cdot rect(\eta)\quad d\eta=\\=\exp(-\pi in\xi)\cdot tri(\xi)$$ Is it correct?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Your integral should contain another phase term depending on the integration variable $\eta$. In your calculation this term probably cancels out because of a sign error.

Comment: I added the integral to my answer.

Comment: And so, which is the final result for 2.?? Thanks

Comment: I've added some more detail to my answer. If you do the very simple final step yourself you'll see that the result is not a triangle.

Comment: I did understand my mistake about the sign, but not your derivation.

Comment: The result is zero when I try to evaluate the integrals you were writing there. Thanks. Please add this to your answer so I accept it and it will be the final and complete answer.

Comment: I've added the final solution.